# JQuery Ajax returning success with nonexistent url parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So I have this code in one of my Laravel's views:
(there is no such url as "nonexistenturl", I just made it up)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
    addToCart();
  });

  function addToCart(){
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "nonexistenturl",
      data: { msg: 'hi' },
      success: function(data){
        alert('success');
      }
    })
   }

});
</script>
```

And the alert message is showing, I don't understand why. Thanks for the help!

**Edit 0:**
Now I tried the same code in another View and I get an error as it must be, but I don't know why it works in the other view yet.

**Edit 1:**

For some reason if I run the javascript code I posted from one specific view, the following code is being executed:

```
public function show($id)
{
  $recipe = \App\Recipe::find($id);

  return view('recipes.show')->with('recipe', $recipe);
}
```

The Laravel's route for this is:

```
Route::get('recipe/{id}', 'RecipesController@show');
```

So it's as if the ajax request was using another url, the one from the current view...

**Edit 2**

I feel so stupid now. As charlietfl suggested it was using the url "recipe/nonexistent". So all I have to do is use: url: "{{url('route')}}"

Thanks for your help everyone :)

Comment: Now I tried the same code in another View and I get an error as it must be, but I don't get why yet.

Comment: I suggest checking your browser console to see the actual URL. For example, when I try your code on JSFiddle, the URL is `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/nonexistenturl?msg=hi`, which is valid and "successful". On the other hand, using `http://nonexistenturl` does not fire "success".

Comment: Inspect the actual response in browser dev tools network tab. Sounds like your framework is still returning a 200 status for that route and not a 404

Comment: As @charlietfl suggested, make sure calling that non-existent URL doesn't return a response code 200 instead of 404.

Comment: Another reason it might be working is if you are in the `recipe` directory when you make this call url is likely `http://yourdomain.com/recipe/nonexistenturl` . Without validating the url params at server it might appear like a  valid route in your routing

Answer (score 0):

This probably mean that Laravel is returning some type of web page, even if there is no data on it, it returning something would be considered a success. A good way to debug this would be to alert the data, and it if returns an object then alert data.responseText.

```
alert(data.responseText);
```

It would also help to navigate the any fake urls you are making to see what Laravel returns on them.
**EDIT**

Try specifying json as the return type, I believe it defaults to text.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "nonexistenturl",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { msg: 'hi' },
  success: function(data){
    alert('success');
  }
})
```

Comment: It's returning the html code of the view I'm sending the request from. This is only from an specific view, the others return an error. Any idea why? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Try changing the ajax code so that it expects json to be returned. By default I believe that it will accept any type of text as a success.

Add this to your ajax.

dataType: "json"